# R, is there any function able to search and return only the first element that qualifies for something in a vector/list/matrix row/column?

Tags: r

Following the title, for example, I want to get just the first even number in (1,4,5,2,7,45,8). I can do loop, I can use which(), but they seem not efficient enough. Do you have any better ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**
Results from timing the solutions for:

1) the vector approach: `tst[tst %% 2 == 0][1]`

2) `firstEven` (`Rcpp`)

3) `for` loop with `break`

4) `match()`

using two vectors, `tst2` with first as even, `tst` with last as even:

```
tst <- c(rep(1, 10000000), 2)
tst2 <- c(2, rep(1, 10000000))
```

`system.time` results:

```
         test time
1     for.tst 8.11
2    for.tst2 0.00
3     cpp.tst 0.05
4    cpp.tst2 0.05
5  vector.tst 0.47
6 vector.tst2 0.47
7   match.tst 0.61
8  match.tst2 0.61
```

For loop has best case and worst case, the other two are the same in both cases, but using the `Rcpp` library is much faster.

For loop with a `break` statement to stop searching list

```
for (i in c(1,4,5,2,7,45,8)) {
    if (i %% 2 == 0) {
        print(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this is the method I currently use. I just hope the R gurus has already planted something like this inside R, or not?

Comment: @user2961927 Yea definetly, like you said the match() function is written in C (or fortran?) and will do the same thing, maybe slightly faster, I try to to check

Comment: So if time reallllllly matters, use `Rcpp`, if not a naive vector-based  approach is fine. Using `for` is risky as it gives hugely variable timings depending on the depth of the search.

Comment: Great! I'll write C++ codes to handle similar situations from now on. At first I couldn't believe match.tst and match.tst2 have so close running time, and it really bummed me out when I got the same results. I thought inside match() there must be a loop with a break kind of thing..

Comment: @thelatemail I'm sort of surprised that the vectorized base-R solutions (match and vector) are still an order of magnitude slower than the Rcpp solution. I would have expected them to be about on the same level, maybe with the Rcpp solution being faster with more even numbers in the vector, since it has the immediate break. But that isn't the case with this test. That is, I would have thought that the match.tst2, vector.tst2, and cpp.tst2 would have all been around the same times.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley To a first appromixation, R is slower even when it dispatches to C code because it checks for NAs etc. Correctness first, speed second. Which is not a bad rule to live by.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my first attempt with Rcpp. I don't really know C++, but this seems to work, and since it breaks after finding the first even number, and the explicit for loop runs in compiled code, it should be very fast.

```
>   library(Rcpp)
>   cppFunction('
+           int firstEven(IntegerVector x) {
+               int n = x.size();
+               for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
+                   if (x[i] % 2 == 0) {
+                       return x[i];
+                   }
+               }
+           }'
+           )
>   firstEven(c(1,2,3,4))
[1] 2
>
```

It is definitely a naive solution (e.g., no check if there isn't an even number in the vector).

Comment: Excellent! I think this is the fastest way left to make it work.

Comment: +1 for trying C++ despite what your mother told you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first even number in your example, you can use `%%`

```
> x <- c(1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 45, 8)
> x[x %% 2 == 0][1]
## [1] 4
```

Comment: this searches the whole list then pulls out the first that satisfied

Comment: Right, but what if there aren't any evens in the list?  The `for` loop returns nothing, and `i` will equal the last entry.

Comment: Hi RScriv, thank you for your answer! But it seems your method still will examine every element in the vector at first. I am processing many very long vectors, so I hope R would immediately return once it found a qualified element.

Comment: Then 6pool's answer would be better here.  However, this way at least returns `NA` if there are no even numbers in the list.

Comment: @RScriv the for loop wont return the last entry because there is a test for even

Comment: If I want to get the first element equal to 5, match() is a perfect option because it returns immediately after 5 found. Does R have similar functions, not just bounded to "equal"?